# Is there a migration manager working with PLESK 11?

Tags: migration, plesk

I'm desperately trying to get a working "migration manager" on my fresh machine running PLESK 11.0.9. The MM has not been installed by default - and I couldn't find any compatible installer - neither on the PLESK-Website/-board nor using google.

Did someone manage to get the Migration Manager running on PLESK 11?  OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Migration manager can be installed in "Tools & Settings" > "Updates and Upgrades" - this link run autoinstaller's UI on port 8447, where you can choose "Plesk migration manager" component and install it.

Comment: uhh... after a few changes to the firewall this really worked. :-) Thanks.